# Does the tense match?"Even though + present tense, past tense"?

Tags: difference, tense

Can I say "Even though my friend **does** not like traveling, she introduced me a very useful travel App when I had a headache to find one."? Or should I say "Even though my friend **did** not like traveling, she introduced me a very useful travel App when I had a headache to find one."

Background：my friend always does not like traveling, but last time she introduced a travel App to me.

How to express this meaning as a native English speaker?

Comment: Yes, your sentence is fine. The description 'does not like travelling' is true of your friend at all times, not just the day when she showed you the app.

Comment: "[...] she introduced **me to** a very useful app when finding one was giving me a headache"

Comment: Both versions ("backshifted" or not) are fine. It's just that the backshifted version is more tightly focused on the time in the past when the friend did something, whereas the Present Tense version is more appropriate if you want to retain focus on the friend herself - who hopefully is *still* your friend, so your next utterance might be something like *As you can see, she's a very good friend to have!*.

Comment: Note that *I **had a headache** to find one* is ***not*** idiomatic. You'd need to say something like *Finding one **was a headache** [for me].*

Comment: The sentence is not quite right. There are a couple of grammatical errors. "Even though my friend does not like traveling, she introduced me **to** a very useful travel app when I had a headache **finding** one."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's [*she introduced **me to** a very useful app*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/introduce-sb-to-sth)

Let's talk about your question. If you search for the usage of present simple on the Internet, you can see several usages like:

> 1. To give instructions or directions.
> 2. To express fixed arrangements.
> 3. To express future time, after conjunctions like after, when, before, as soon as, until... etc.
> 4. To express habits, general truths, repeated actions or unchanging situations, emotions and wishes.

In your example, it's the fourth rule. It's fine to say **"does not like traveling"** as the description is true **at all times**, not just the day when she showed you the app.